# How to efficiently cache dynamic content in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, dynamic, dynamic-data

"[Blogging on App Engine, part 1: Static serving](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/10/Blogging-on-App-Engine-part-1-Static-serving)" describes how to properly handle dynamic content caching when using python with GAE. It covers DownStream caching, conditional GETs, 404 responses, Etags... I haven't found anything as comprehensive related to a targeted asp.net mvc implementation.

What would be the most elegant/readable/maintainable way to implement this when targeting asp.net mvc platform ?

**EDIT:** "[Enabling Client-Side Caching of Generated Content in ASP.NET](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38123)" provides one with some interesting insight about the subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combining the **OutputCache attribute** (which Yannis suggests) and modifying the **HttpContext** should work.

There's some information about conditional GETs and Etags:
[Conditional GETs and Etags](https://web.archive.org/web/20170513111341/http://optimizeasp.net/conditional-get)

If someone knows a better way to solve this problem: I'm interested :-)